# Why is tput failing silently on TERM=vt100

Tags: terminal, colors, tput

I'm using zsh with iTerm as my terminal emulator on macOS and my environment has `TERM=xterm-256color` by default.

If I run `tput setaf 3` it exits with code 0.

If I set `TERM=vt100` and run `tput setaf 3` it exits with code 1 (indicating failure).

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vt100` has no `setaf` capabilities which `tput` notices and fails on. The definitions can be found in the `terminfo(5)` database:

```
% TERM=xterm-256color infocmp | grep setaf
        setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
% TERM=vt100 infocmp | grep setaf
%
```

A `vt100` is rather old and the manual mentions nothing about supporting such fancy things as colors (apparently there were different colors for the floor mats you could purchase with a vt100...).

Comment: lol’d at the mats.

Answer (score 3):

VT100s never did color (see [ncurses FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)).  So the terminal description lacks the feature, and as [documented](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-EXIT-CODES), tput returns an error.

When the vt100 was introduced in 1976, color was a costly feature, not used on commodity terminals.  Color was standardized a few years later (at least, [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm) edition 2 in 1979 provides this information; edition 1 is unavailable for inspection).